# Generate next.js static pages from folder of markdown

Tags: next.js

I've building a static next.js site and want to generate a set of static pages from a folder of markdown docs (but for the purpose of this question could be any thing - text files etc). Imagine I have this docs folder:

```
/docs/foo/bar.md
/docs/foo/baz.md
/docs/bar/foo.md
...
/docs/foobar.md
```

The only way I can discover the full URL slugs is at build time where I can recurse the docs folders and discover these paths:

```
/docs/foo/bar
/docs/foo/baz
/docs/bar/foo
...
/docs/foobar
```

Normally, if I knew about the diff sub-routes I could add files like this:

```
pages/docs/foo/[page].js
pages/docs/bar/[page].js
```

...however I don't know about these sub-folders at code time to be able to do this, only at build time when I recurse the docs.

The nearest thing I can find would be a catch-all route like this:

```
pages/docs/[...slug].js
```

I know that I could easily link to a route such as `/docs/foo/bar` in the app and I know that I could get the slug in the page itself like in [this example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/catch-all-routes/pages/post/%5B...slug%5D.js), but I'm not sure if/how can I generate the static paths I need in this file using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this one just now which wasn't immediately obvious to me...

In `getStaticPaths`, due to the `[...slug].js`, next.js expects the provided slug to be an array for the path parts, so building an array of arrays solves it:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Load the docs from the file system and convert their relative docs paths to arrays
  const docs = [["foo", "bar"], ["foo", "baz"], ["bar", "foo"], ["foobar"]];

  return {
    paths: docs.map((doc) => {
      return {
        params: {
          slug: doc,
        },
      };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

...then `getStaticProps` will be called per array above and I can retrieve the markdown and prepare the content as props for the page component.